# strange behaviour when populating a select list in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm populating a select list using razor and its giving me some strange results.  The items in the list contain spaces, the text created is ok, but the value has been split into sections for each word in the text description.  Here's my razor code

```html
<select name="fromReport[]" id="multiselectReport" class="form-control" size="15" multiple="multiple">
                                                        @foreach (var item in Model.AvailableReports)
                                                        {
                                                            <option value=@item>@item</option>
                                                        }
                                                    </select>
```

and the resulting HTML

```html
<select id="multiselect_toRpt" class="form-control" name="toReport[]" size="15" multiple="multiple">
<option value="All" trades="" activity="" last="" week="">All Trades Activity Last Week</option>
<option value="All" trades="" for="" delivery="" last="" month="">All Trades For Delivery Last Month</option>
<option value="Energy" costs="" report="">Energy Costs Report</option>
</select>
```

so its created a section in the definition for each word in the text, why is this ?

Comment: What's in `Model.AvailableReports`. What is `AvailableReports`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `value` attribute value in quotes. Single quotes or double quotes will work.

`<option value="@item">@item</option>`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.AvailableReports)
                                                        {
                                                            <option value="@item">@item</option>
                                                        }
```